# Does Epplus package require to write to a file?

Tags: c#, epplus, memorystream

Does epplus package requires to write to a file right away? or can it generate a memoerystream as an output?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14048542/275643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't *generate* a stream. It *writes to* a stream. That stream can be a `FileStream`, `MemoryStream`, or any other stream.