# EPPLus Not Returning File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

EPPLus is not returning a File. No errors on build or console errors.

Network Tab is showing completed 200 ok.

```
public ActionResult DownloadExcel(EntityReportModel erModel, string filename)
{
     var dataResponse = iEntityViewService.LoadEntityView(new EntityViewInput
     {
          SecurityContext = SessionCache.Instance.SecurityContext,
          EntityViewName = "Ticket",
          Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> {
              {"MinTicketDateTime", "04/26/16"}

          }
     });

     var table = dataResponse.DataSet.Tables[0];

     filename = "NGLTICKETS";
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
     using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
     {
          ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(filename);
          ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);

          return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", filename);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not manipulate your output stream, hence you will get no result.

You can fill your stream by doing [`var stream = new MemoryStream(pack.GetAsByteArray())`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14048542/2441442). As alternative [`pack.SaveAs(stream)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6460978/2441442).

So your code should look something like that:

```
 using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
 {
      ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(filename);
      ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);

      var stream = new MemoryStream(pack.GetAsByteArray()); //Get updated stream
      return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", filename);    

      //or simple return File(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", filename)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Christian . Unfortunately those additions did not give me any more result. ;(

Comment: Could you define *not returning a File* more specificaly @RayKoren? Do you get a white browser page (then what does the browser networktab say)? Ist the excelfile corrupt?

Comment: When I click my button I watch the network tab and the function runs and I see: DownloadExcel 200 xhr VM391:1 1.3 KB                           Request URL:https://localhost/Custom/Ticket/DownloadExcel
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=NGLTICKETS Content-Length:0
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: The page does not refresh. Literally nothing visibly happens on the front end. There is no message returned and no file download dialogue triggered. I appreciate the help. I have tried many many variations on this so far...

Comment: @RayKoren see my updated answer. Looks like `MemoryStream` overload does not work the same as `FileName` overload I used. Does this version work?

Comment: SO that gave me a new result, but it is an issue I encountered in the past and thought I had mitigated. I get a popup with random characters in it. [screenshot](https://ibb.co/nQFFLk) looks like I am getting 13k of data back in that request tho...

Comment: Seems like you are loading the excel file via ajax. Not sure about the topic binaryfiles and ajax @RayKoren

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143923/discussion-between-ray-koren-and-christian-gollhardt).