# EPPlus error reading file

Tags: c#, openxml, epplus

using code like

```
using OfficeOpenXml;  // namespace for the ExcelPackage assembly
…
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\mynewfile.xlsx"); 
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile)) { … }
```

I get an exception error of

> 'IBM437' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining
>   a custom encoding, see the documentation for the
>   Encoding.RegisterProvider method. Parameter name: name

Any ideas as to what the problem could be?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: I have got it to work

Comment: post an answer so others have some use of it too

Answer (score 7):

if your project is .net core edit your project file then add

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and in your startup.cs

add

```
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Comment: I have it in the startup constructor and it works! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the ZIP file reader (`ZipInputStream`). You need to add the encodings like `windows-1252` manually:

1. `dotnet add package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`
2. `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);`

More info here: [.NET Core doesn't know about Windows 1252, how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870084/net-core-doesnt-know-about-windows-1252-how-to-fix/37870346#37870346)

Comment: Where do you apply these steps ??